# Element if dragged inside mcustomscrollbar does not move scroll downwards

Tags: javascript, html

I have few draggable elements inside Scrollbar (`mcustomscrollbar`). If I try to drag this element to the droppable area which is below the visible area of scroller, then the scroll does not automatically move downwards.

Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use the `mCustomScrollbar` with `jquery-sortable` (https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) -
I needed a way to move the scroller content while dragging the sortable element to get to some hidden below content.

I used the `onDrag` event of jquery-sortable to move the scroller using `mCustomScrollbar` `scrollTo` method:

```
        onDrag: function ($item, position) {
            // original functionality - better be safe
            $item.css(position);

            var sign = '-';
            if ($this._prevDragPositionY > position.top) {
                sign = '+'; //console.log('scrolling up');
            } else { //console.log('scrolling down'); }
            $this._prevDragPositionY = position.top;

            $('.jsScroll').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", sign + "=75", {
                scrollInertia: 300,
                scrollEasing: "linear"
            });
```

I hope this helps :)